# Visual Studio Custom Item Templates for PCLs

Tags: visual-studio-2013, portable-class-library, visual-studio-templates

I am trying to create an item template compatible with a PCL.

This question has already been asked and answered but it appears that a later update to VS means the solution is no longer working. Link to original question below:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8ecb51d9-a53e-4078-a47f-0195ea98cf6d/create-item-template-for-portable-class-library-pcl?forum=vsx

My template currently looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="Item" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
    <TemplateData>
        <Name>Class</Name>
        <Description>Template Description</Description>
        <Icon>Icon.ico</Icon>
        <AppliesTo>CSharp + MultiTarget</AppliesTo>
        <DefaultName>Class.cs</DefaultName>
    </TemplateData>
    <TemplateContent>
        <References>
            <Reference>
                <Assembly>System</Assembly>
            </Reference>
        </References>
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true">Class.cs</ProjectItem>
    </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Most of the above is lifted straight from the above link and backed up from this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497698.aspx.

Intellisense is complaining about xsi:schemaLocation and AppliesTo.

I'm using VS 2013 Professional Update 4.

Can anyone explain how to correctly create a PCL template or explain what needs to be done to get the above to work?

Comment: I exported a class to a new item template from a PCL project.. This item template still doesn't show up for PCL projects, but it shows up on Library projects. Makes me think something is definately broken here..